# Errors when trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04 from 20.10

Tags: updates, 20.10

Whenever I try and run software updater I just get the error "Failed to download repository. information please check your internet connection." and whenever I run `sudo apt update` I get the error

```
Get:6 https://packages.riot.im/debian default InRelease [2,892 B]
Err:6 https://packages.riot.im/debian default InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C2850B265AC085BD riot.im packages <packages@riot.im>
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://packages.riot.im/debian default InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C2850B265AC085BD riot.im packages <packages@riot.im>
E: The repository 'https://packages.riot.im/debian default InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`
```

Comment: I think the key here could be "Updating from such a repository can't be done securely..." It sounds like you may have added a third-party repo at some point to your software updater.  I'd check there first.  If you go to Software & Updates and click on the Other Software tab you may find the offending repo there.  If so, try deselecting it and proceeding with your upgrade.  There should be a reference to the offending repo packages.riot.im.

Comment: Disable the broken repository, then try again

Comment: There is no repository with that name so I can't disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update repository GPG key by using command below

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C2850B265AC085BD

wget -q -O - https://packages.riot.im/element-release-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q -O - https://packages.riot.im/element-release-key-2020.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q -O - https://packages.riot.im/riot-release-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

and then install all updates with new dependencies to your current system by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: For me this did not work without changes because my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/riot-im.list` contained `[signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg]`. I guess this might be different depending on when and how you installed element originally. If this is the case for you need to run `apt-key` commands with the `--keyring /usr/share/keyrings/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg` option to update the key. It appears to me that using a dedicated keyring for such special repo is slightly more secure.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (from https://linuxintosh.wordpress.com/2021/04/26/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-c2850b265ac085bd-riot-im-packages/ ):

```
$ sudo ls -la /usr/share/keyrings/  | grep riot
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2887 Apr 16  2019 riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg

$ sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg

$ sudo wget -O /usr/share/keyrings/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.riot.im/debian/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg

$ echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.riot.im/debian/ default main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/riot-im.list
```